# Insert SQL - MM variable?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

do i need to change the data type of the DATE column to VARCHAR?

```
SQL> INSERT INTO BW_CLASS VALUES(`PC101', `MS OFFICE BASICS', `INDIANA JONES','18','1000',
  2  TO_DATE('01-10-2013 10:30 AM', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:Mm PM'),
  3  TO_DATE('05-10-2013 10:30 AM', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:Mm PM'),
  4  `1276';
SP2-0552: Bind variable "MM" not declared.
SQL> desc bw_class
Name                                                                Null?    Type
CLASS_ID                                                            NOT NULL CHAR(5)
CLASS_NAME                                                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(40)
PROFESSOR                                                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS                                                            NUMBER(6,2)
COST                                                                           NUMBER(6,2)
START_DATE                                                          NOT NULL DATE
END_DATE                                                            NOT NULL DATE
ROOM_NUM                                                                     VARCHAR2(3)
```

Comment: In the code that you posted, you appear to have a mix of single quote characters ' and the accent character `  Single quotes begin and end strings.  The accent character does not.  You'll need to replace all the accents with single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use this query

```
INSERT INTO BW_CLASS VALUES('PC101', 'MS OFFICE BASICS', 'INDIANA JONES','18','1000',
    TO_DATE('01-10-2013 10:30 AM', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI PM'),
    TO_DATE('05-10-2013 10:30 AM', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI PM'),
    '1276';
```

Answer (score 1):

You used a wrong quote. All parameters need to be quoted using `'` in both sides, but you used ` in some places. So you should try this:

```
INSERT INTO BW_CLASS VALUES('PC101', 'MS OFFICE BASICS', 'INDIANA JONES','18','1000',
    TO_DATE('01-10-2013 10:30 AM', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI PM'),
    TO_DATE('05-10-2013 10:30 AM', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI PM'),
    '1276';
```

And you don't need to write `2 3 4` at the beginning of lines, why did you do that?

Comment: the 234 was from the copy/paste from my Oracle window, sorry.